# Establishing connecting using Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing a program that connects Client machine to Server using RMI and so far I keep getting `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`.

Here is my code;

Interface

```
public interface ServerInterface extends Remote
{
public String getMessage() throws RemoteException;

}
```

Server

```
public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface 
{
int portNumber = 7776;
String ipAddress;
Registry registry;

public Server() throws RemoteException
{
    try
    {
        ipAddress = "192.168.0.104";
        System.out.println("IP Address: " + ipAddress + " Port Number: " + portNumber);
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.rebind("ServerFour", this);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Remote Exception Error");
    }
}

public String getMessage() throws RemoteException
{
    String output = "Connected to Server";

    return output;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        Server server = new Server();

    }
    catch (RemoteException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Remote Exception in Main");
    }

}

}
```

Client

```
public class Client 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, RemoteException, NotBoundException 
{
    try
    {
        ServerInterface server;
        Registry registry;

        String serverAddress = "192.168.0.104";
        String serverPort = "7776";

        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress, Integer.valueOf(serverPort));

        server = (ServerInterface)(registry.lookup("ServerFour"));

        String serverMessage = server.getMessage();

    System.out.println("Servers Message: " + serverMessage);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


}
```

For now I just want Client to call on the method in the ServerInterface and print out its message, but I can't seem to get it to work. I get the Exception message shown above when I start the Client.

When I start the Server it returns this:

IP Address:  client4/127.0.1.1 Port Number: 1234

**Update:**

I've changed the port number to 7776
Ran rmiregistry 7776 &

This is what I get when I start Server and run netstat -anpt
https://i.stack.imgur.com/drQUJ.png

Now on the Client side I'm getting this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBcZZ.png

Comment: Firewall on server blocking port 1234? Can you telnet the service?

Comment: Please clarify on "It does the same thing". Connection refused if you use telnet? Then either the server is not up and running or access is forbidden.

Comment: Yes when I try to telnet it returns connection refused.

Comment: So that server isn't reachable from that client. Nothing to do with RMI. Can you telnet to another port on the server? e.g. 23? Also when you get an exception, *never* substitute your own message. Always print the one that comes with the exception. Otherwise you have no hope of knowing what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the RMI `Registry` is bound to `localhost` (cf. 127.0.0.1 - I assume the 127.0.1.1 is a typo?), yet try to contact it from the client on `192.168.0.104` - that won't work, since nothing presumably is listening on that interface! Try changing the client `serverAddress` to `127.0.0.1` instead.

The command `netstat -anpt` (or on Windows: `netstat -anbt`)  is your friend when you want to see what processes are bound on which interfaces (the `t` is for TCP by the way).

This is the way to bind the Registry to a specific IP (eg. `localhost`),

```
registry = 
    LocateRegistry.
        createRegistry( portNumber , 
                        new RMIClientSocketFactory() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public Socket createSocket( String host, int port ) throws IOException
                            {
                                return new Socket( "127.0.0.1" , port );
                            }
                        } , 
                        new RMIServerSocketFactory() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public ServerSocket createServerSocket( int port ) throws IOException
                            {
                                return new ServerSocket( port , 0 , InetAddress.getByName( "localhost") );
                            }
                        } );
```

Cheers,

Comment: Incorrect. He isn't 'bind[ing] the server to localhost'. He is binding a remote object to an RMI Registry running in the localhost, which is the only Registry you can bind to. This has nothing to do with the ServerSocket's bind-address, which by default is 0.0.0.0 unless you specify an RMIServerSocketFactory that does something else, which he hasn't done. His code is correct.

Comment: My formulation was very generic - apologies for that - I have edited my answer a bit. It's correct what you state, yet it appears that the Registry is bound to localhost ('`IP Address: client4/127.0.1.1 Port Number: 1234`') so I think my suggestion is still valid.

Comment: No. The Registry was created with a port number and no host-address, so it gets bound to 0.0.0.0 just as above. The program is merely printing out the value of localhost: that's not evidence of what anything is bound to.

Comment: And changing the client 'serverAddress' to 127.0.0.1 certainly cannot help unless client and server are both running in the same host, in which case there wouldn't be a problem in the first place.

Comment: ...which is why I suggested to `netstat` and see what's happening. I agree that the registry *should* be bound to 0.0.0.0, yet `InetAdress.getLocalhost()` returns 127.0.1.1 (or localhost if that's actually a typo) which is a bit unusual? I maintain that the most likely cause is that the registry isn't bound on 192.168.0.104, but neither you or I can determine that - only @Nick can.

Comment: There is simply no evidence here that the Registry isn't bound to 0.0.0.0, and there is no mechanism present by which it could possibly have done so; and I can indeed determine that, by inspection of his code. It therefore cannot possibly be considered the 'most likely cause'. Equally, there is nothing unusual about 'localhost' mapping to 127.0.0.1, assuming the obvious typo: that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Well how do I bind Server Registry to its address (192.168.0.104)?

Comment: Did you figure out if the `Registry` was actually bound to `localhost/127.0.1.1`? I have edited my answer to illustrate binding to a specific IP.

Comment: @Anders, I've updated my code in my original post and posted screenshots of what I'm dealing with currently.

Comment: Is the client and server running on the same machine? If not, are you absolutely sure of the IP `192.168.0.104`? Does the communication cross a router/firewall? What is the output of `ifconfig -a` / `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: @Nick All this stuff about the listen/bind address is a red herring. Ignore it. As you aren't specifying socket factories, the default bind address for all RMI servers including the Registry is 0.0.0.0. The real issue is the firewall question and the questions I asked in comments below your question. Please continue the discussion there, not here.

Comment: @AndersRostgaardBystrup The amount of code you had to add to your post to get the Registry to bind to a specific address should surely have convinced you that this is not the problem, *as the OP isn't using that code.* You seem to be now trying to get him to use that code, which is a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: @EJP actually Nick asked about it. I'm trying to help Nick here, I don't really see concrete suggestions from your side...

Comment: @AndersRostgaardBystrup My comments here concern your answer, and my concrete suggestions appear below his answer. I think it's a firewall, and my questions are sufficient to prove or disprove that hypothesis. I'm not just guessing about it, and I'm not guessing about the bind address either.